# Can't access full python module from file, but can from shell

Tags: python, shell, module, python-module

Maybe I am completely missing something here but when I run this code form the shell it works:

```
import nltk
tokens = nltk.word_tokenize("foo bar")
```

and returns:

```
['foo','bar']
```

But when I but this into a file and execute it with python -u "path/to/file/myfile.py" it returns

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'word_tokenize'
```

I've tried reinstalling and every thing i can think of. Let me know if you need any more information.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: What is your python script's filename?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have more than likely called your file `nltk.py` so python is trying to import from that as opposed to the actual `nltk` module. Just rename your `.py`file.

Comment: Thanks so much!  I'm sort of a noob with python.

Comment: No worries, trust me you are not the first!